# Scroll on fixed position div

Tags: javascript, css

The entire popup-div is visible, and when I scroll vertically, it follows.

[image]

Only half of the popup-div is visible, and when I scroll vertically it follows, but it's impossible to view the second part of the popup-div. **How can this be achieved?**

[image]

css code:

```
  .popup
{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9002;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:solid 1px #000000;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.popupbackground
{
    background-color:#111;
    opacity:0.65;
    filter:alpha(opacity=65);
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 500;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

I'm working with ASP.NET, if the code-behind is needed to answer this question I will provide it.

I have read about solutions such as setting the overflow parameter to auto or scroll, but haven't gotten that to work.

Update follows below:

Now the popup is scrollable vertically as wanted, but only if the scrollbar is visible horizontally.
[image]

Here, it's not possible to scroll vertically because the scrollbar is not visible, and scrolling horizontally in the browser just forces the popupdiv to follow along.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code (the content of the pupup is just for testing):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.popup
{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9002;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:solid 1px #000000;
    top:10%;
    left: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
    height:80%;
    width:40%;
}

.popupbackground
{
    background-color:#111;
    opacity:0.65;
    filter:alpha(opacity=65);
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="popupbackground">
</div>
<div class="popup">
a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

specify the height of the popup to 80% and top:10%

Comment: Thanks, that partly worked. See my updated post for an explanation of when it doesn't work.